# jQuery Ui - Swapping thickbox for UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, thickbox

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is depreciated and causes problems when used within jQuery UI Tabs. Before moving to using tabs I was simply calling thickbox which worked as normal, with the url of my remote source included. Is there a generic way that jQuery UI dialogs can be made to work the same was as the thickbox solution?

I was calling thickbox like so:

```
<a href="URLHERE" class="thickbox" disabled title='Select a value from the list provided'><img border=0  src='images/zoom.png'></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced with UI Dialogs:

```
$('.thickbox').click(function(){
        var href = $( this ).attr("rel");
        var dialogTitle= $(this).attr("title");

        $("#testDialogID").load(href, function() {
            var container = $(this);
            container.dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                opacity: false,
                title: dialogTitle,
                modal: true
            })
        });

    });
```

Comment: The first answer answer is incomplete. Do we need to create a div with the "testDialogID" id? Nothing in that answer tells me how to actually implement jQuery-UI-dialog as a replacement for thickbox.